# Does Recycleview in Xamarin.Forms need to be implement on IOS separately?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, android-recyclerview, xamarin.forms

As you know Xamarin.Forms output is for all Android, IOS and UWP. Can I add a Recycleview Nugat to the Xamarin.Forms and do implement the code just one time on Xamarin.Forms and the code to be executed on both Android and IOS?  Or I have to implement Recycleview on Android and IOS separately ?

Comment: `RecyclerView` is an Android concept. It would only be relevant in Xamarin.Android. You would use an `UICollectionView` in iOS.

Comment: If you're using xamarin forms you should use ListView, use recyclerview to xamarin android

Comment: @JonDouglas How can I say to the app when the mainpage started each platform opens it's mainpage that contains Recycleview on Android and UICollectionView on IOS?

Comment: @FabriBertani Listview is too slow and even with implementing catch strategy.